# Solving A Partial Differential Equation Using Separation of Variables

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I am having issues with this problem. I am asked to use the method of separation of variables to solve this:

- $u^\prime(t) = k u^{\prime\prime} (x)$ for $0 \leq x \leq L$ and $t > 0$
- $u^\prime(x)(o,t) = u^\prime(x)(L,t) = 0$ for $t > 0$
- $u(x,0) = 1 + 2 \cos(3 \pi x/L)$ for $0 \leq x \leq L$

I get that we are looking for a solution in the form of the product of two functions. What is throwing me off is that I can't understand what my book is talking about, I can follow their examples but I am not learning anything from that because they skip steps (we are using a graduate level textbook for an undergraduate course, go figure right??) So if someone can explain to me how to work with these so I can actually understand what's going on instead of just copy what the book is doing that would be awesome.

Answer (score 2):

To solve by the method of separation of variables to put $u(x,t)= F(x)  G(t)$ so that $u^\prime(t) = k u^{\prime\prime} (x)$ becomes $F(x) \, G^\prime(t) = kF^{\prime\prime}(x) \, G(t)$ and the differentials are full derivatives and not partial derivatives. After this you put all the functions of (just) $x$ on one side of the equation and all the functions of $t$ on the other side. This gives

$$\frac{G^\prime(t)}{G(t)} = k \frac{F^{\prime\prime}(x)}{F(x)} $$

Since the left hand side is just a function of $t$ and the right hand side is just a function of $x$ the only way that this can be true for all $x,t$ is that both sides are equal to a constant, say $\lambda$. You then apply the given conditions to determine the possible values of $\lambda$.

Comment: It isn't clear at what level you required an answer.